# What or who is "Minami" in "Search for Minami"?

Tags: japanese-language, culture, kare-kano

In chapter 63 of *Kare Kano*, Arima appears on a television show called *Search for Minami* after he is recognised for his academic and athletic prowess. The beginning of the show is depicted in the manga, and it begins with:

> Hello! And welcome to the popular "Search for Minami!" Today, we're visiting Hokuei High school … Hokuei High School is Kanagawa prefecture's top school. Today's "Minami" is going to be out of this world … Well, then, let's bring our guest, Soichiro Arima-kun!

(I removed short exclamations that did not appear to originate from the key show host in this section, such as "I'm excited myself!") What exactly does "Minami" mean in this context? That it is left untranslated suggests that it is supposed to be an important name, but I have trouble finding anything that would fit the context. Is there some sort of cultural knowledge that I am missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Minami means Minami Asakura in the anime [Touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_(manga)).

When the anime aired, it was very very famous and everyone knew the character.
She is a heroine in the manga and she likes sports.

One daily news show called [Super Time](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/FNN%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A0#.E3.81.9D.E3.81.AE.E4.BB.96.E7.95.AA.E7.B5.84.E6.94.BE.E9.80.81.E5.BD.93.E6.99.82.E3.81.AB.E9.96.A2.E3.81.99.E3.82.8B.E3.82.A8.E3.83.94.E3.82.BD.E3.83.BC.E3.83.89) started a new corner "Search for Minami!" which finds sports girl every day and interviews them.

It's an 80's show, no one knows that now, but the author of Kare Kano likes these kinds of random jokes.